# How to skip apply function for missing value cell in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataset as below :

```
import pandas as pd
from workdays import workday, networkdays 
path = r'C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\learning\abc\1\test_labtat\lab.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(path)





    start date  End date       HT            D
0   2022-02-08  NaT         indirect         BL
1   2022-01-20  NaT         direct           None
2   2022-01-23  NaT         direct           None
3   2022-01-23  NaT         direct           None
4   2022-02-07  NaT         direct           None
5   2022-02-07  NaT         direct           None
6   2022-02-09  NaT         direct           None
7   2022-02-09  NaT         direct           None
8   2022-02-10  NaT         direct           None
9   2022-02-11  2022-02-13  direct           None
10  2022-02-16  NaT         direct           None
11  2022-02-16  NaT         direct           None
12  2022-02-16  NaT         direct           None
13  2022-01-15  2022-01-21  direct           None
14  2022-01-17  2022-01-17  direct           None
```

I write the code to calculate networkdays for these row have date value in column 'End Date' :

```
df.loc[df['D']=='BL', 'D'] = df.apply(lambda x: networkdays(x['start date'],x['End date']) if not pd.isnull(x['End date']) else x['End date'],axis=1)  #if column'D' value = 'BL' then skip its value , just apply for the rest cell in D with criterias  ['End date'], ['Start date'] not null
```

however, I got the error below, I don't know how I got this, could you please help look ?

my expect output like below:

```
    start date  End date    HT     D
0   2022-02-08  NaT indirect      BL
1   2022-01-20  NaT direct  None
2   2022-01-23  NaT direct  None
3   2022-01-23  NaT direct  None
4   2022-02-07  NaT direct  None
5   2022-02-07  NaT direct  None
6   2022-02-09  NaT direct  None
7   2022-02-09  NaT direct  None
8   2022-02-10  NaT direct  None
9   2022-02-11  2022-02-13  direct  3
10  2022-02-16  NaT direct  None
11  2022-02-16  NaT direct  None
12  2022-02-16  NaT direct  None
13  2022-01-15  2022-01-21  direct  5
14  2022-01-17  2022-01-17  direct  1
```

Comment: Only the first row has `D='BL'` but the `End date` is `NaT` so your output will be empty...

Comment: I found the solution already, thank you , nice weekend Bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem comes from how you call the `apply` function.

By default, `apply` works on **columns** [1], but you can change that using the `axis` parameter.

Something like this might give you the expected result:

```
df['days'] = df.apply(
    lambda x:
        networkdays(x['start date'], x['End date'])
        if not pd.isnull(x['End date'])
        else "can not call"
    , axis=1                # use axis=1 to work with rows instead of columns
)
```

[[1]](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Comment: thank you Bro @Matei, missing axis = 1 in the function , btw i just change the question for my lab , could you please assist ?